# Gaussian filter in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I am looking for a way to apply a Gaussian filter to an image (tensor) only using PyTorch functions. Using numpy, the equivalent code is

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define 2D Gaussian kernel
def gkern(kernlen=256, std=128):
    """Returns a 2D Gaussian kernel array."""
    gkern1d = signal.gaussian(kernlen, std=std).reshape(kernlen, 1)
    gkern2d = np.outer(gkern1d, gkern1d)
    return gkern2d

# Generate random matrix and multiply the kernel by it
A = np.random.rand(256*256).reshape([256,256])

# Test plot
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(A*gkern(256, std=32))
plt.show()
```

The closest suggestion I found is based on [this post](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/gaussian-filter-for-images/20597):

```
import torch.nn as nn

conv = nn.Conv2d(in_channels = 1, out_channels = 1, kernel_size=264, bias=False)
with torch.no_grad():
    conv.weight = gaussian_weights
```

But it gives me the error `NameError: name 'gaussian_weights' is not defined`. How can I make it work?

Comment: I think `gaussian_weights` should be a kernel made from a gaussian, like with `scipy.signal.gaussian`

Comment: Yupp I also had the same idea. So now the question becomes: is there a way to define a Gaussian kernel (or a 2D Gaussian) without using Numpy and/or explicitly specifying the weights?

Comment: Maybe this https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/is-there-anyway-to-do-gaussian-filtering-for-an-image-2d-3d-in-pytorch/12351/3 can help you

Comment: pytorch implementation here: https://forums.fast.ai/t/proposal-to-add-gaussian-blur-to-data-augmentation/38604/2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a Pytorch class to apply Gaussian Blur to your image:

```
torchvision.transforms.GaussianBlur(kernel_size, sigma=(0.1, 2.0))
```

Check [the documentation](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.transforms.GaussianBlur.html) for more info

Answer (score 9):

> Yupp I also had the same idea. So now the question becomes: is there a way to define a Gaussian kernel (or a 2D Gaussian) without using Numpy and/or explicitly specifying the weights?

Yes, it is pretty easy. Just have a look to the function documentation of [signal.gaussian](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.gaussian.html). There is a link to the [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/f2ec91c4908f9d67b5445fbfacce7f47518b35d1/scipy/signal/windows.py#L976). So what the method is doing is the following:

```
def gaussian(M, std, sym=True):
    if M < 1:
        return np.array([])
    if M == 1:
        return np.ones(1, 'd')
    odd = M % 2
    if not sym and not odd:
        M = M + 1
    n = np.arange(0, M) - (M - 1.0) / 2.0
    sig2 = 2 * std * std
    w = np.exp(-n ** 2 / sig2)
    if not sym and not odd:
        w = w[:-1]
    return w
```

And you are lucky because is the straightforward to convert in Pytorch, (almost) just replacing `np` by `torch` and you are done!

Also, note that `np.outer` equivalent in torch is [ger](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.ger.html#torch.ger).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the question actually asks for a *convolution* with a Gaussian (i.e. a Gaussian blur, which is what the title and the accepted answer imply to me) and *not* for a *multiplication* (i.e. a vignetting effect, which is what the question's demo code produces), here is a pure PyTorch version that does not need `torchvision` to be installed (otherwise `torchvision.transforms.GaussianBlur()` can be used instead, as has been proposed by [Mushfirat Mohaimin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73164332/7395592)):

```py
from math import ceil

import torch
from torch.nn.functional import conv2d
from torch.distributions import Normal


def gaussian_kernel_1d(sigma: float, num_sigmas: float = 3.) -> torch.Tensor:
    
    radius = ceil(num_sigmas * sigma)
    support = torch.arange(-radius, radius + 1, dtype=torch.float)
    kernel = Normal(loc=0, scale=sigma).log_prob(support).exp_()
    # Ensure kernel weights sum to 1, so that image brightness is not altered
    return kernel.mul_(1 / kernel.sum())


def gaussian_filter_2d(img: torch.Tensor, sigma: float) -> torch.Tensor:
    
    kernel_1d = gaussian_kernel_1d(sigma)  # Create 1D Gaussian kernel
    
    padding = len(kernel_1d) // 2  # Ensure that image size does not change
    img = img.unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze_(0)  # Need 4D data for ``conv2d()``
    # Convolve along columns and rows
    img = conv2d(img, weight=kernel_1d.view(1, 1, -1, 1), padding=(padding, 0))
    img = conv2d(img, weight=kernel_1d.view(1, 1, 1, -1), padding=(0, padding))
    return img.squeeze_(0).squeeze_(0)  # Make 2D again


if __name__ == "__main__":

    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    img = torch.rand(size=(100, 100))
    img_filtered = gaussian_filter_2d(img, sigma=1.5)
    plt.subplot(121)
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.subplot(122)
    plt.imshow(img_filtered)
    plt.show()
```

The code uses the basic idea of a [separable filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_filter) that Andrei Bârsan implied in a comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69056163/7395592). This means that convolution with a 2D Gaussian kernel can be replaced by convolving twice with a 1D Gaussian kernel – once along the image's columns, once along its rows. This is more efficient in general, as it uses 2N rather than N² multiplications per pixel for a kernel of side length N.

So in the provided code, we first create a 1D Gaussian kernel with `gaussian_kernel_1d()`, which we then apply twice in `gaussian_filter_2d()`.

Some more notes on the code:

- The parameter `num_sigmas` controls how many standard deviations and thus how much of the bulge of the Gaussian function we actually sample for producing the convolution kernel. As the Gaussian function theoretically has infinite support (meaning it is never zero), this presents a trade-off between accuracy and kernel size (which affects speed and memory use). A length of `3 * sigma` should be sufficient for the two halves of the support usually, given that it will cover 99.7% of the area under the corresponding Gaussian function.
- Rather than using `Normal().log_prob().exp_()` for producing the kernel, we could explicitly write
  the function of the normal distribution here, which might be a bit more efficient. In fact, we could write `kernel = support.square_().mul_(-.5 / (sigma ** 2)).exp_()`, thus (1) altering the values of `support` in-place (as we won't need them, any longer) and (2) even omitting the normalization constant of the normal distribution (as we must normalize the kernel by its sum before returning it, anyway).
- Although we use `conv2d()` rather than `conv1d()`, effectively we still have two 1D convolutions, as we apply a N×1 and 1×N kernel in `conv2d()`. We could have used `conv1d()` instead, but the code is much simpler with `conv2d()`.
- In more recent PyTorch versions, we can use `conv2d(…, padding="same")`, rather than calculating the padding amount ourselves. In either case, using `conv2d()`'s `padding` parameter implies padding with zeros. If we wanted more padding options, we could manually pad the image with `torch.nn.functional.pad()` before the convolution instead.

Answer (score 1):

Used all the codes from above and updated with Pytorch revision of `torch.outer`

```
import torch
def gaussian_fn(M, std):
    n = torch.arange(0, M) - (M - 1.0) / 2.0
    sig2 = 2 * std * std
    w = torch.exp(-n ** 2 / sig2)
    return w

def gkern(kernlen=256, std=128):
    """Returns a 2D Gaussian kernel array."""
    gkern1d = gaussian_fn(kernlen, std=std) 
    gkern2d = torch.outer(gkern1d, gkern1d)
    return gkern2d

# Generate random matrix and multiply the kernel by it
A = np.random.rand(256*256).reshape([256,256])
A = torch.from_numpy(A)
guassian_filter = gkern(256, std=32)

ax=[]
f = plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))
ax.append(f.add_subplot(131))
ax.append(f.add_subplot(132))
ax.append(f.add_subplot(133))
ax[0].imshow(A, cmap='gray')
ax[1].imshow(guassian_filter, cmap='gray')
ax[2].imshow(A*guassian, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It's worth pointing out that it's not 100% needed to pre-compute the gaussian blur outer product. You get the same result if you just convolve the image with the horizontal, then vertical filters (in either order). In fact, for larger filter sizes (say >20) the process will be much faster than using the outer-product kernel, as your will be performing fewer computations (the filter complexity goes from K^2 to 2K).